# Why doesn't my code accept whitespace in getline(cin, *userInput)?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to take a user input, encode or decode using the rot13 method and then display the user input with the text encoded/decoded.

I am not sure what to try as the algorithm for encoding/decoding using the rot13 method was provided by my professor. I think it's something related to it but I'm not sure where to start.

I have tried using `cin >> *userInput` but when entering a string with white space, the white space still doesn't show up.

For example, when I put `hello world` and I get `uryybjbeyq`in return. No space at all.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string encrypt(string input) {
  int inputSize = input.size();
  int index = 0;

  while (index != inputSize) {
    if (input[index] >= 97 && input[index] <= 109)
      input[index] = input[index] + 13;
    else if (input[index] >= 110 && input[index] <= 122)
      input[index] = input[index] - 13;
    else if(input[index] >= 65 && input[index] <= 77)
      input[index] = input[index] + 13;
    else if(input[index] <= 78 && input[index] <= 90)
      input[index] = input[index] - 13;

    index++;
  }
  return input;
}

int main() {
  bool prog = true;
  char ans;
  char ans1;
  string* userInput;
  string* cypher;
  cypher = new string;
  userInput = new string;

  do {
    cout << "Do you want to encode or decode a message? Y/N" << endl;
    cin >> ans;
    if (ans == 'y' || ans =='Y') {
      prog = true;
    } else if(ans == 'N' || ans == 'n') {
      break;
    }

    cout << "OK, do you want encode or decode? E/D" << endl;
    cin >> ans1;

    if (ans1 == 'e' || ans1 == 'E') {
      cout << "What is the message you want to encode?" << endl;
      cin.ignore();
      getline(cin, *userInput);
      *cypher = encrypt(*userInput);
      cout << *cypher << endl;
      delete userInput;
      delete cypher;
      cypher = nullptr;
      userInput = nullptr;
    }

    if (ans1 == 'd' || ans1 == 'D') {
      cout << "What is the message you want to decode?" << endl;
      cin.ignore();
      getline(cin, *userInput);
      *cypher = encrypt(*userInput);
      cout << *cypher << endl;
      delete userInput;
      delete cypher;
      cypher = nullptr;
      userInput = nullptr;
    }
  } while (prog == true);

  cout << "Goodbye." << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Never use [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code integers, they make your code unreadable. Use `' '` in your code instead of 32. Be aware that in 2021 [UTF-8](http://utf8everywhere.org/) is used everywhere. Use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as your compiler (invoked as  `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) and [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) as your debugger to understand the behavior of your program. See also [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) website

Comment: `string*` and `new string` seems like a bad idea in this program. And generally. It's also pointless to ask if they want to encode/decode. They wouldn't have run your program otherwise. Instead, give a 'quit' option when asking to encode or decode.

Comment: And why not clang++ and lldb? Seems weird to get specific about that. The better thing would have been to ask them what they're using in their class (I get that gcc is not a stretch for most courses, but still).

Comment: Not related to the question but you don't need to delete `userInput` and `cypher` after using them, since they are basically in-use for the entirety of main(). In fact I'm not even sure how you're assigning to them after deleting them, this should crash the program. There's actually no reason to use `new` to create empty strings here at all. You can just remove all of the calls to `new` as well as the `delete`'s and assignments of `nullptr`.

Comment: In this lab we were learning about heap memory, we had to make a pointer string and delete the string so it's no longer stored in memory. This is what I've been taught so far so thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if(input[index] <= 78 && input[index] <= 90)
    input[index] = input[index] - 13;
```

The condition is malformed as it's supposed to be checking for character between 78 and 90.

```
else if(input[index] >= 78 && input[index] <= 90)
    input[index] = input[index] - 13;
```

This will give the desired output.

Also, you don't need to use pointers here. `string userInput;` is sufficient for this program and you can get rid of all the `new` and `delete` and `nullptr` assignment.

Comment: You know it's a hard class when you have to fix your professor's provided code to make the assignment work ;)

Comment: @LayneBernardo Haha.. True that

Comment: Oh wow I guess it's something I have to look out for in the future then.. Didn't realize he would make mistakes in the code he provides us